# Getting error "Certificate is valid for ServerCommonName, not ClientCommonName"

Tags: ssl, go

I am trying to do a TLS authentication of a remote server. This server is configured with two certificates (one root and one it's own). Locally, I have the same root certificate. I am doing a TLS handshake (to validate that server can be trusted) by creating a client locally. However, on doing that, I am getting error: `x509: Certificate is valid for ServerCommonName, not ClientCommonName`. When I am trying to validate certificates present by server, ideally, the certificate chain of server should have a root cert that I trust and this is fine. Not able to understand why getting this particular error.

Can someone help? Below is the code...

```
func CheckTLSendpoint() error {
    getDecoded()
    var tlsConfig tls.Config
    cer, _ := tls.X509KeyPair(ClientCertPem, ClientKeyPem)

    // Checking verification of server certificate by the client is required or not
    rootCA := x509.NewCertPool()
    rootCA.AppendCertsFromPEM(RootCaPEM)

    tlsConfig = tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            rootCA,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cer},
        ServerName:         "ClientCommonName", //this is common name of my client certificate
    }
    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

    rAddr := "10.20.30.40:3325"

    conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", rAddr, 10*time.Second)
    defer conn.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("TCP connection error : %s", err.Error())
    }

    c := tls.Client(conn, &tlsConfig)
    defer c.Close()

    err = c.Handshake()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("TLS connection error :  %s", err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: If the server presents an unexpected certificate then that is an issue with the server's configuration, not with the client (assuming the expectation is correct, of course).

Comment: Wait, you put the client's name in the ServerName field? Why? It's called ServerName because it's supposed to be set to the server's name. It's the server that needs to prove it is who you want it to be. The client's name is irrelevant when verifying the server's identity.

Comment: oh... ok. Actually, I thought that for 2 way SSL, server will check this field to validate my certificates. That is why I used that here.  Thanks @Peter for clarifying that.

Comment: Now that error is gone. Now I am getting `EOF` :(
Let me try checking for this.